# React-Native pass an array of colors to a FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React-Native and I'm stuck trying to pass an array of colours as a background colour to a component of my FlatList component. (Hopefully that makes sense)

Here's a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.
[App homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wcj.png)

My Code:

```
 class TubeFetch extends Component {
state = {
    lineDetails: [],
    colors: [
        "#994F14",
        "#DA291C",
        "#FFCD00",
        "#007A33",
        "#EB9CA8",
        "#7C878E",
        "#8A004F",
        "#000000",
        "#10069F",
        "#00a3e0",
        "#4CC1A1"
    ]
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
    axios
        .get("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status")
        .then(response => this.setState({ lineDetails: response.data }));
}

render() {
    const { nameStyle, statusStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.lineDetails}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TubeCard>
                        <CardSectionTitle
                            style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.colors }}
                        >
                            <Text style={nameStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
                        </CardSectionTitle>
                        <CardSectionStatus>
                            <Text style={statusStyle}>
                                {
                                    item.lineStatuses[0]
                                        .statusSeverityDescription
                                }
                            </Text>
                        </CardSectionStatus>
                    </TubeCard>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Whilst the above provides no errors my CardSectionTitle remains a backgroundColor of white. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: do you expect backgroundColor to accept an array rather than a single color?

Comment: Rethink your `lineDetails` data structure. What relation does color have with the data? Can/should `color` just be a property of each individual piece of data in `lineDetails`? Right now, I see that `lineDetails` is coming from an API, while `colors` is just hard coded. There are a lot of edge cases and it's not entirely clear why they are decoupled. If you can think through a proper data structure first, then you'll have an easier time creating the UI from it.

Comment: Actually I don't think that there is any connection between what he asked and api request part, he is just asking how to render background color for each cell @MichaelCheng

Comment: Hey Douglas, I believed backgroundColor could accept an array of colors at least, however please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BatuG. The point I was getting at is that if `color` were another value at the per `lineDetails` level, then it would be accessible via `item` in `renderItem`. The only other alternative would be to use what you're suggesting which is to pass the `index` but that would run into the issue of `out of bounds` errors in the cases where the API pulls in more items than there are colors to match it to. You can add cases to handle it, but it would be messier. Since s/he asked for a hint, I just gave a hint.

Comment: There is no connection between the api and the colors. I would just like each item in the list to have a different background color pulled from the colors array. Like I mentioned I am new to React-Native and coding in general and so probably going about this the wrong way.

Comment: No you can't just simply push array to backgroundColor property

Comment: Hi @BatuG. thanks for confirming and commenting thus far. If possible could you advise on a way of achieving what was show within my screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @James_ Ok, since you're new to coding in general, I have a few pointers for you to consider. First is to think about the edge cases like I mentioned above. Second is to ask yourself why you put `colors` in `state`. In React, `state` is for data that can change. I don't know if you ever intend to change it, but having it as a `prop` or a `defaultProp` might be a better choice. Last, check the docs for `FlatList`'s `renderItem` and see if you can get @BatuG.'s answer working. If you get stuck, edit the question with what you ran into and I'll try to help you along while I'm still free.

Comment: @James_ I have edited my answer and if you copy and paste that line it would probably work I do not have react native on my pc right now, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

In your code each time you will get the same color probably the first one. You should use your index values in order to get different background color for your items in list.  Something like

`<CardSectionTitle style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[this.state.lineDetails.indexOf(item)%this.state.colors.length]}}>`

would help you. Keep in mind that you are writing something similar for loop for each cell and yes you are in the right direction.

Ok full example, I got that from react native docs and edited a little bit. I hope you get the point.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
const colors= [
        '#994F14','#DA291C','#FFCD00','#007A33','#EB9CA8', '#7C878E',
        '#8A004F','#000000','#10069F','#00a3e0','#4CC1A1'
]
export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item,index}) => <Text style={[styles.item,{backgroundColor:colors[index%colors.length]}]}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlatListBasics);
```

Comment: Closer to a full answer, but you still need to handle the edge case where the data (`lineDetails`) returned from the API exceeds the length of `colors`. You should also revert that `indexOf` edit you made since that isn't a good way of handling it.

Comment: in upper paragraph I didn't want to use index to just write it in single line xd @MichaelCheng

Comment: Yeah, I understood that but it's really not a good way of handling it because there is an `index` arg in `renderItem`.

Comment: Hi Guys, Apologies for not coming back sooner. It works! Thanks for all your help especially@BatuG. I am now looking into understanding how this piece of code works. @MichaelCheng in terms of an edge case could you not just set a default backgroundColor of for example black and then if the api does return more data than colors the next line will have a backgroundColor of black?

Comment: @James_ If you look at the history of edits on the answer, my comments will make more sense. I was trying to guide both of you to an acceptable, higher quality Q&A. WRT your idea, yes, it would be fine so long as you don't attempt to access an out of bounds index. There's usually more than one solution to the problem which is why I was looking for feedback rather than answering.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCheng you've been a great help.